# How to activate a user when user verify his/her phone number using Twilio in Django? If user is not verified how to deactivate a user?

Tags: python, django, authentication, twilio

How to activate a user when the user verifies his/her phone number using Twilio in Django? If the user is not verified how to deactivate a user?

Here is My code.

in forms.py file

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=17)
    country_code = forms.CharField(max_length=3, initial='+19')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']
```

in views.py

```
def signupPage(request):
form = CreateUserForm()

# if request.method == 'GET':
#     return render(request, 'user/signup.html')

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()

        # ====================================

        request.session['phone'] = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        request.session['country_code'] = form.cleaned_data['country_code']
        authy_api.phones.verification_start(
            form.cleaned_data['phone'],
            form.cleaned_data['country_code'],
        )
        return redirect('token_validation')

        # ====================================

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'user/signup.html', context)
```

in views.py

Is there any problem in token_validation function?

```
def token_validation(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TokenForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        verification = authy_api.phones.verification_check(
            request.session['phone'],
            request.session['country_code'],
            form.cleaned_data['token']
        )
        if verification.ok():
            request.session['is_verified'] = True
            messages.info(request, 'Your Phone Number is Verified, Please Enter Your Information.')
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            return redirect('verified')

        else:
            for error_msg in verification.errors().values():
                form.add_error(None, error_msg)
else:
    form = TokenForm()
return render(request,'user/token_validation.html', {'form': form})
```

Here I am getting an error  `user.is_active = True`
`NameError: name 'user' is not defined`
when I am trying to make the user active again.
How to make the user active again when the user verifies his token.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Each request has its own context, so in the request to `token_validation` your previous reference to a `user` no longer exists.

You should save your user ID in the session, along with the phone number and country code, then load the user from the database using that ID.